# How to make an independent div over other divs?

Tags: css

I made a theme with a navigation menu at top like this;

```
width="100%" height="100"
```

The left area contains customers logo at 100px height. However, they want logo to be bigger in side, say 200px. I don't want to increase the size of my div's size, instead, I want to make a new div at 200px-200px, put the logo inside it, and put that logo div over the navigation div.

How can I make an independent div like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you mean? ofcourse the style should be done in separate css; not in the html!

```
<div id="topnavigation" style = "height:100px;width:100px;position:relative;z-index:5;">
  <div id="logo" style="width:200px;height:200px; position:absolute;z-index:10; top:15px;left:15px;"> <img src ="logo.jpg" width="200px" height="200px"/> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, it is. How did we do this, with position: absolute?

Answer (score 3):

Create the div inside the navigation div, but give it `position:absolute; width:200px; height:200px; top:0; left:0;` that should place it top left of the navigation without affecting the height of the navigation.

Alternative is it place the logo **before** the navigation element do use the same styles to position them both starting in the same page location.

Example:

```
#logo{
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
}


#navigation{
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}

<div id='logo'></div>
<div id='navigation'></div>
```

I'd recommend experimenting to find the best solution because I can't see your whole project.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample jsfiddle for you:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZzaZp/

and copying the code here:

HTML:

```
<div class="navigation">
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.navigation{
    height:100px;
    background-color:#f3f3f3;
    position:relative;
}

.logo img{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border:0px;
    display:block;
}

.logo{
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border:2px solid #eee;
    left:20px;
    top:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the CSS sample which worked for me...

```
.logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; /* can adjust div position by changing left and top etc */
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px; /* width and height require to place it on top of certain size its an added advantage */
}
```